# Matebook 16 ryzen 5 4600h audio problem

Tags: sound, speakers, audio-jack

I went through almost every formula and tried many Linux versions, thinking that the problem was in the kernel, and now it seems that the sound card installed with Pop OS, which is one of the Ubuntu facilities, should be identified, but there is no sound coming from either the speakers or the headphones. If anyone knows, please help.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0jEJS.png)

Comment: Only Ubuntu and *official* flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Pop forum. (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Pop OS so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: It's helpful if you're specific with details; including release/product details as Ubuntu LTS releases have kernel stack choices.. and until we know what release you're we won't know what options exist for you. The only detail you're specific on is Pop OS which is Ubuntu based, does not use Ubuntu kernels (using System 76 kernels) & includes *proposed* or *testing grade* packages that aren't default in Ubuntu (*which strives for stability*). Use a Pop OS forum if that's your chosen OS.